# SSH to Mac port 22: Connection refused - after Remote Login enabled

Tags: macos, ssh, login, sharing, ventura

On my Macbook on Mac OS Ventura (aka macos 13.4) I enabled Remote Login in order to access this laptop via ssh:

> I've set the Mac's System Preferences > Sharing > Remote Login to accept connections

I also disabled firewall (also Little Snitch) and restarted my Macbook, however it refuses all connection attempts via ssh (even LAN).

**Nothing**.

I get this error message:

```bash
    ssh macbook.local 
    ssh: connect to host macbook.local port 22: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 2):

I've searched the internet and found out some helpful terminal commands. So open up terminal on the destination host/laptop and:

1. Let's check if the service is really enabled (it was not):

```
    sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin
    Remote Login: Off
```

2. Let's enable it using the same terminal session, and check again:

```bash
sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on
sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin
Remote Login: On
```

3. Now remote access should work.
4. Note about remote access keys (RSA keys are now deprecated since 2020 and disabled by default in OpenSSH 8.8, see [OpenSSH 8.8 Release Notes](https://openssh.com/txt/release-8.8) ):

In my case it seems MacOS ssh service did not accept RSA (only ED25519), so I had to login by typing the password.

Add the following lines to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on the destination host:

```bash
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Or even better generate an ED15519 key.

Good luck!

Comment: I think points 1 and 2 should be in the question and the question is why does it not work 3. is the issue. For 4 quote the openssh release notes to explain why this works. A good answer gives references if at all possible.

Comment: MacOS Ventura has changed which RSA algorithms it allows for appropriate security.  Off the top of my head, I think the two `Algorithms` lines are essentially degrading your ssh security by allowing the older specification.